# PIL Blurry at Low Resolutions

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, blurry

I'm building a 2D pixel art game for personal use, and I'm keen not to create 200 odd NPCs, so I wrote a python script to take a .png component (head, hair, body, accessories) and add them together. These files are only 64, 128 in size, so are very small.

No matter what I use, I always end up with a strange grey blur around the faces and some of the colours are slightly shifted (even if they were originally taken from the same picture). (see picture below)[image: see here]

I've tried newimg.paste(img, (0,0), img), and I've even tried a loop where I've taken each pixel and (if it isn't (0,0,0,0),) replace the old pixel. I still end up with this bizarre zombie effect! It's not in any of the individual images from what I can see.

I was expecting to see the images overlaid one on top of the other. Instead I'm seeing this bizarre pixelated blur of all the images.

Is this something to do with how I've loaded it in? (Image.open(filepath)). Is it something to do with the img.save and img.show functions?

Looking for any experience someone might have.

Comment: It could be an artifact of the Alpha channel from the NPC image interacting with the existing pixels of the destination. Not sure there's anything you can do about it…

Comment: Could also be related to saving the file -- `img.save()` accepts a range of parameters that could affect final quality: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png maybe try saving with `compress_level=0`?

Comment: It seems like the color resolution/colorspace of the images is getting messed with; like, JPGs have a 4:2:0 color space, which means that colors are stored as half the resolution as brightness. So, make sure nothing like that could be going on at any point. Could have to do with decoding as well, not sure. Just a wild guess.